# theorems that depend on the embedding of an affine variety into the affine space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a theorem regarding an affine variety $Y$ of $\mathbb{A}^n$.

> Question 1: What does the phrase "$\mathcal{T}$ does not depend on the embedding of $Y$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$" mean?

My understanding is that $Y$ is trivially embedded into $\mathbb{A}^n$ via the inclusion map $i:Y \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^n$, since after all $Y$ is given as the zero locus of a finite set of polynomials of $A=k[y_1,\dots,y_n]$, where $y_i$ are the coordinate functions on $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Does it mean that if $B$ is some finitely generated algebra over $k$ that is an integral domain such that it is isomorphic to $A/I_Y$, then the affine variety defined by $B$ also satisfies $\mathcal{T}$?

> Question 2: What is an example of a theorem $\mathcal{T}$ that does depend on the embedding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**
You are correct: a property of an affine variety $Y$ is independent of its embedding in some affine space $\mathbb A^n(k)$ if that property can be read off from the  $k$-algebra $\Gamma(Y,\mathcal O_Y)$ of global regular functions on $Y$.

**Question 2**
The simplest example of a property that *does* depend on the embedding $Y\hookrightarrow \mathbb A^n(k)$ is the codimension of $Y$.
For example if $Y=\{\star\}$ is just a point, it can be embedded into any affine space as   $Y= \{(0,\cdots,0)\}\subset \mathbb A^n(k)$ and its codimension is then $n$.
Thus the codimension can be  any natural number according to the embedding: a strong dependence on the embedding indeed!
[You state your question in terms of a theorem: the theorem would be "$Y$ has codimension $n$"]

Comment: If Y is embedded via the inclusion maps in n-affine space and some m-affine space as well then how can we show that the corresponding coordinate rings of Y are isomorphic as k-algebras?

Comment: The reason I ask this is that I have been told that the coordinate rings really capture the geometry of the affine variety...the  embedding of an affine variety in a bigger space does not matter because you get an isomorphism as k-algebras of the corresponding coordinate rings...so in that sense being an affine variety is a geometrically intrinsic property